# unable to parse String date "2019-02-23T13:59:13.312401"

Tags: parsing, gson, jodatime

I am trying for many hours to parse this date String which is returned by Shodan. "`2019-02-23T13:59:13.312401`" ISO format is throwing exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2019-02-14T10:16:35.313860" is too short
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
```

I am using Joda DateTime  library with Google Gson. Anyone knows which format is this and how can I convert it to DateTime object from String.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 1):

Shodan stores the timestamps in ISO 8601 format which you can read more about here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

And see here for a previous answer on parsing the format using Joda time:

[Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date/2202300)